# Sync between progress bar update and another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to make some kind of dynamic effect onto a html/php combat script.

I've got in one hand a function to progressively display each opponent turn, such as :

```
<button id='fight'>Fight</button>
<div class='log right'> A hits B </div>
<div class='log left'>  B hits A </div>
<div class='log left'>  B hits A </div>
<div class='log right'> A hits B </div>
<div class='log left'>  B hits A </div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('.log').hide();                                                 
  $('#fight').click(function() {                                        
    $('.log').each(function(i) {                                    
      var dir = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 'left' : 'right';        
      $(this).delay(i * 500).toggle('slide', {direction: dir}); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And i've got in my other hand another function to display and update health bar using jQuery UI progress bar, similar to this :

```
<div id='progressBar'></div>

<script>
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($health_array); ?>;
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(updateBar, 500);
function updateBar() {
  if (arr[i] == 0) {clearInterval(interval);}
  $('#progressBar').progressbar({
    value : arr[i]
  });
  i++;
}
</script>
```

For now, the health bar decreases way faster than the divs show up on screen. Obviously that's not good, they need to be synced. I have no clue on how to put more delay in my updateBar() function according to the slide toggle of the divs. I'm not even sure i'm taking the problem in the good way (JS isn't my strong suit)...

Comment: Your initial script block seems to be missing a lot of closing elements.

Comment: Indeed, i fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do. Sort of like a game, you're looking to lower the progress bar after each action.

Created this fiddle that may help: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ze89w87j/

**HTML**

```
<button id='fight'>Fight</button>
<div class='log right'> A hits B </div>
<div class='log left'> B hits A </div>
<div class='log left'> B hits A </div>
<div class='log right'> A hits B </div>
<div class='log left'> B hits A </div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div id='progress-a' class='power'>Player A</div>
  <div id='progress-b' class='power'>Player B</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.power {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .4em .2em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var arr = {
  a: 100,
  b: 100
};

var i = 1;

function updateBar(p) {
  $('#progress-' + p).progressbar("value", arr[p]);
  i++;
}

$(function() {
  $('.log').hide();
  $('#fight').click(function() {
    $('.log').each(function(i) {
      var dir = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 'left' : 'right';
      var player = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 'a' : 'b';
      var $log = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $log.toggle('slide', {
          direction: dir
        });
        arr[player] -= 15;
        updateBar(player);
        console.log(arr);
      }, i * 500);
    });
  });
  $('.power').progressbar({
    value: 100
  });
});
```

As you had not shown example data, I had to make some assumptions. If you have player A and B, there will be some action that reduces the progress bar. So I created 2 bars. As the array lowers, the progress bar is updated.